# Manifest returning "Unrecognized manifest key 'brower_action'." and nothing popping up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm trying to build a (very begginer) chrome extension. For some reason, my manifest returns both "Unrecognized manifest key 'brower_action'." and "Unrecognized manifest key 'premissions'.".

I'm not sure how to fix it, and when I click the extension in chrome nothing pops up. 
Here is my manifest:
{
    "name": "trial",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version": "0.1",

```
"description": "does stuff, I do not know yet",

"brower_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

"premissions":["notifications"]
}
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in both manifest keys. See below the correct key names.

```
"description": "does stuff, I do not know yet",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions":["notifications"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `action` don't use `broswer_action`

```
{
"name":"jokes",
"version":"0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"action":{     
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_icon":"logo.png"
},
"icons": {
    "128":"logo.png"
},
"permissions":["activeTab"]
}
```